# Drawer Layout hamburger and toolbar not visible despite working nav drawer?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am currently creating a navigation menu without using fragments. I've seemingly created the working system that opens classes and keeps the navigation bar present at each stage by using a `BaseActivity` and inheriting it into the classes that need the drawer. However upon loading the app seemingly the 3 bar 'Hamburger' icon isn't present and neither is the toolbar at the top (See photo). The navigation bar does seemingly work as I can swipe from the left and click to load other classes. I feel like my `onCreate()` in my `BaseActivity` is missing something but with googling I can't seem to find a solution.

Image of current issue:

[image: Image of current issue]

Image of Nav Bar Working with issue in background:

[image: Image of Nav Bar Working with issue in background]

This is my base activity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                Intent anIntent;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.nav_homepage:
                        anIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homepage.class);
                        startActivity(anIntent);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_add_roster:
                        anIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), add_roster.class);
                        startActivity(anIntent);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_check_schedule:
                        anIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), schedule.class);
                        startActivity(anIntent);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my homepage which is what is loaded initially:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class homepage extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout contentFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame); //Remember this is the FrameLayout area within your content_main.xml
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.homepage, contentFrameLayout);
    }
}
```

Here's my activity main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, add the code below in your BaseActivity :

```
    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

EDIT:

Enable the home button in your `onCreate` function of BaseActivity as well :

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

There is missing a toolbar layout in your xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this helps;

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Tried this in my googling, no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Nada, force closes with a null pointer. I'm using a NoActionBar theme so this is probably the cause for that...

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: The two line of code must be after setSupportActionBar(toolbar); , is it your case ?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my idiocy. I was missing my toolbar xml! Sometimes it's hidden in plain sight! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and in app_bar_toolbar.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in content_main.xml, use this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.esec_0052.fingertips.FingerTipMainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_finger_tip_main">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```